# Alternative strings in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Sadly I have to ask this question but after noodling on this problem the whole morning, I give up.  Searching online, man pages, documents, none of it seems to give me a conclusive answer to what I try to do.

Looking for a regular expression for the PHP function [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match a string against a pattern.  Now that pattern is what gives me headaches.

The pattern should express the following: string starts with "_MG_" or "IMG_" or "DSC_", followed by four digits, followed by an optional "-N" where N is another digit.  For example, "IMG_0123" or "DSC_9876-3" are valid.  Everything else should be rejected.

I came up with various patterns, but none of them seems to work.  For example, I tried

```
(_MG_|IMG_|DSC_)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9])?
```

and this in different variations with ( ) and apostrophes around various sub-expressions and using ? vs {0,1} and whatnot.  (I experimented using grep, but got no matches still.)  Yes, I know I need to add "/.../" for PHP, but here I left it out for readability's sake.

Can I even express this in a single expressions, or will I have to call the matching function several times?  If several matches are required, I might be better off writing a small parser for this particular string matching myself.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code that I'm working with

```
// Iterate over all images in this gallery folder.
if ($h = opendir($dir)) {
  while (($f = readdir($h)) !== false) {

    // Skip images whose name doesn't match the requirement.
    if (0 == preg_match("/(_MG_|IMG_|DSC_)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]){0,1}/", $f)) {
      continue;
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

And this also allows image names like "_MG_7020-1-2.jpg" or "_MG_7444-5-6.2.jpg" or "IMG_6543_2_4_tonemapped.jpg" but that's not what I want to allow.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Can you include a specific code snippet that fails along with a test string that you would expect to match?

Comment: Do you need to add a backslash before the final part of your example regexp? `(_MG_|IMG_|DSC_)[0-9]{4}(\-[0-9])?` seems to match both your examples.

Comment: @andrewsi - The backslash shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Jens - The regex looks correct, so the problem is likely somewhere else.  Post your PHP code.

Comment: It's force of habit - I tend to escape characters like dashes, on the grounds that it won't hurt and might help.

Comment: After the edit I realized that the pattern matching works ok, but it recognizes sub-strings as well as complete strings.  All the strings that match incorrectly are too long and they actually start with a correct pattern, but then continue on.

So, using this expression `"/(_MG_|IMG_|DSC_)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]){0,1}\.(jpg|JPG)/"` I seem to get what I need.

However, how can I use grep like ^ and $ in PHP patterns?

Answer (score 1):

I ran this as well:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match('/(_MG_|IMG_|DSC_)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9])?/','IMG_0123-3',$matches );

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "IMG_0123-3"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "IMG_"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "-3"
}
```

Seems ok, unless I'm missing something, or unless what you're referring to is that preg_match returns false if not all your matchers () match.

Note the return type for preg_match from the php doc:

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop searching after the first match. preg_match_all() on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject. preg_match() returns FALSE if an error occurred.

So you may be looking to really use preg_match_all() in fact

Comment: I posted some code and test names in my EDIT of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $array = array('IMG_0123', 'DSC_9876-3', '_MG_1234', 'DSC_fail');

    foreach($array as $arr) {
        if(preg_match("/_MG_|IMG_|DSC_[0-9]{4}[-0-9]*/", $arr)) {
            echo $arr . ' => TRUE <br />';
        } else {
            echo $arr . ' => FALSE <br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

The above works as expected for me.

Comment: This is a slightly different expression: note the [-0-9]* at the end which would allow 0-n occurrences.  Only one ought to be allowed.  Also, the [-0-9] .. not sure if that describes "dash followed by a single digit" correctly.

Comment: @Jens You are right, the [-0-9] would allow one character: a `-`, or one digit, 0 through 9 and would not dictate order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original pattern with start and end of string anchor as well as some edits to reduce the pattern length.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4CuhX))

```
var_export(
    preg_grep(
        '/^(?:DSC|[_I]MG)_\d{4}(?:-\d)?$/',
        $array
    )
);
```